# How to apply same column id(value) for different rank values based on partition columns

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto, trino

I have a table with columns and values as given below and trying to  append the same id for the different rank column values which has different id value based on rank but needed to append same id column value for rank values other than 1 also.

have data like this

```
rnk=rank() over(partition by from_app_id, from_app_name, to_app_name
                order by lastseen desc) as rnk
```

INPUT:

```
from_app_id, from_app_name, to_app_name, id,  rnk 
1,           a1,            b1,          id1, 1
1,           a1,            b2,          id2, 2
2,           a1,            a1,          id1, 1
2,           a2,            b2,          id2, 2
```

Output:

```
from_app_id, from_app_name, to_app_name, id,  rnk
1,           a1,            b1,          id1, 1
1,           a1,            b2,          id1, 2
2,           a1,            a1,          id1, 1
2,           a2,            b2,          id1, 2
```

i am trying to find in sql/hive  query

for the rows having same from_app_id, from_app_name, to_app_name will have same ranks which will have corresponding id values which is id1, id2, ...

my requirement is for the different rank values also i need to update the same id column value not the different id value
means in simple rank >1 rows also should have same id value of rank=1

Comment: Sorry what? Can you try to rephrase your requirement please.

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong... You want to update id based on from_app_id , from_app_name , to_app_name right ?

Answer (score 2):

Based on provided input and desired output partitioning on `from_app_name` and `to_app_name` is excess (the provided `rnk` function will actually assign 1 for all rows in the sample data) but partitioning aside (you can figure it out on your real data) - you can just use very convenient [`min_by`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/aggregate.html#min_by) function which is provided by Presto/Trino (which Athena is based on), or similar approach via [`first_value`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/window.html#first_value) window function:

```sql
-- sample data
WITH dataset(from_app_id, from_app_name, to_app_name, id,  last_seen) AS (
    values (1, 'a1', 'b1', 'id1', 1),
    (1, 'a1', 'b2', 'id2', 2),
    (2, 'a1', 'a1', 'id1', 1),
    (2, 'a2', 'b2', 'id2', 2)
)

-- query
select from_app_id,
    from_app_name,
    to_app_name,
    min_by(id, last_seen) over (partition by from_app_id) id,
    # or with the same effect
    # first_value(id) over (partition by from_app_id order by last_seen) id,
    last_seen
from dataset;
```

Output:

| from_app_id | from_app_name | to_app_name | id | last_seen |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | a1 | a1 | id1 | 1 |
| 2 | a2 | b2 | id1 | 2 |
| 1 | a1 | b1 | id1 | 1 |
| 1 | a1 | b2 | id1 | 2 |